# Identify specific integers in column of mixed ints and strings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, integer, object-type

I have a column in a pandas df named `specialty` that looks like this:

```
0         1,5
1           1
2     1,2,4,6    
3           2
4           1
5         1,5
6           3
7           3
8           1
9         2,3
```

I'd like to create a new column called `is_1` that contains a 1 for all rows in `specialty` that contain a 1 and a 0 for rows that don't contain a 1. The output would look like this:

```
0       1
1       1
2       1
3       0
4       1
5       1
6       0
7       0
8       1
9       0
```

I'm not sure how to do this with a column of mixed dtypes. Would I just use `np.where()` with a `str.contains()` call? Like so:

```
np.where((part_chars['specialty'] == 1) | part_chars['specialty'].str.contains('1'), 1, 0)
```

Yep that works...

Comment: Do you want to match any `1`? or just the number `1` but not `10` or `21`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with a regex that matches full words equal to `1`:

```
part_chars['is_1'] = (part_chars['specialty'].astype(str)
                      .str.contains(r'\b1\b').astype(int)
                     )
```

Output:

```
  specialty  is_1
0       1,5     1
1         1     1
2   1,2,4,6     1
3         2     0
4         1     1
5       1,5     1
6         3     0
7         3     0
8         1     1
9       2,3     0
```

###### your solution:

```
part_chars = pd.DataFrame({'specialty': ['1,5', '1', '1,2,4,6', '2', '1', '1,5', '3', '3', '1', '2,3', '21']})
part_chars['is_1'] = np.where((part_chars['specialty'] == 1) | part_chars['specialty'].str.contains('1'), 1, 0)
```

Output:

```
   specialty  is_1
0        1,5     1
1          1     1
2    1,2,4,6     1
3          2     0
4          1     1
5        1,5     1
6          3     0
7          3     0
8          1     1
9        2,3     0
10        21     1  # might be unwanted
```

Comment: Is there any reason my solution wouldn't work?

Comment: @hulio_entredas what dtypes do you have? That should work (with the limitation of also matching other numbers like 11 or 21)

Comment: The dtype for the column is just 'O', so I'm believe the single digits are string and multiple ones are string, i.e. '1,5', etc.

Comment: `O` just means that you don't have a single "vectorial" dtype, you can have integers + strings. What gives `part_chars.to_dict('list')`?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
Your code works well for me.

```
>>> np.where((part_chars['specialty'] == 1) | part_chars['specialty'].str.contains('1'), 1, 0)
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

If you have mixed dtype, you can force the dtype with `.astype(str)`:

```
>>> np.where(part_chars['specialty'].astype(str).str.contains('1'), 1, 0)
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

You can use `str.contains`:

```
part_chars['is_1'] = (part_chars['specialty'].astype(str)
                          .str.contains(r'\b1\b').astype(int))
print(part_chars)

# Output
  specialty  is_1
0       1,5     1
1         1     1
2   1,2,4,6     1
3         2     0
4         1     1
5       1,5     1
6         3     0
7         3     0
8         1     1
9       2,3     0
```

Alternative with `str.split`:

```
part_chars['is_1'] = (part_chars['specialty'].str.split(',', expand=True)
                          .eq('1').any(axis=1).astype(int))
print(part_chars)

# Output
  specialty  is_1
0       1,5     1
1         1     1
2   1,2,4,6     1
3         2     0
4         1     1
5       1,5     1
6         3     0
7         3     0
8         1     1
9       2,3     0
```